# How to group row in ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

Picture1: DataTable
[image: DataTable]

Picture2: Report Setup
[image: Report Setup]

Picture3: Result
[image: Result]

Picture4: Result that I want
[image: Result that I want]

How to group the data if inv_no are same like picture 4? Example like picture 3 GST and rounding is calculate for each row, but I only need to calculate 1 time if the inv_no are same just like picture 4.

My report 'GST' and 'Rounding' setup in picture 2 is also wrong, for 'gst' I only need to sum if inv_no are same, but I have no idea how to write the expression, for 'rounding' I should not use sum also, actually that is no calculation for 'rounding' it can choose any data under column 'rounding' from DataTable as long as the inv_no is match, but I dont know how to write the expression also.

Please help...

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Comment: @AFriend you want which part of detail?